# Show CCLabel for few seconds on touch

Tags: cocossharp

I'm new to Cocos Sharp and have been struggling to implement behaviour from question title. I want to show message to user that will fade or disappear after some period of time, lats say 3 seconds, after user touches some sprite. But I can't figure it out how to do that.

I'm showing CCLabel like this:

```
var scoreLabel = new CCLabel("Touch Menu and Exit button together to exit!", "Arial", 50, CCLabelFormat.SystemFont);
scoreLabel.PositionX = button.PositionX;
scoreLabel.PositionY = button.PositionY + 300;
scoreLabel.AnchorPoint = CCPoint.AnchorMiddleRight;
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 3 seconds, fadeout in 1 second

```
scoreLabel.RunActions(new CCDelayTime(3), new CCFadeOut(1));
```